# Alphavantage.co : Historical data is unable to fetch with 5 min interval

Tags: java, rest, api, alpha-vantage

I am trying to fetch the historical data using [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co) API.

Whenever I try to get historical data with 5-minute intervals by using the URL in the browser, it only displays one month of data. I think it should display more than one month of data.

Am I missing anything?

Sample calls:

1. https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&interval=5min&apikey=CN3J
2. https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=INFY&outputsize=full&interval=5min&apikey=CN3J

Comment: I dont think alphavantage will be providing more historical data. Basically 5 mins data is provided under Intraday data and 15 days data is enough for any analytics IMO.

Comment: As a note, when asking questions on this forum, please be careful to reveal API keys. I hope that is a free key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co) data API, historical data for intraday only goes back a certain number of entries. If you changed the interval to 1 minute, a smaller time window would be given. If the interval was 60 minutes, you'd get a larger time window.

To get all 20 years of data (not intraday) you'd use something like the [daily](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#daily) [weekly](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#weekly), or [monthly](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#monthly).

Comment: Okay , So there is No way to get the historical data for 5min interval using alphavantage.co  (historical data of around 10 years 5min interval)?

Comment: You cannot get 10 years of data with 5-minute intraday intervals at the present time. For that time range, only, daily, weekly, and monthly data work.